# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ has a choice function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, axiom-of-choice

> **Prove that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ has a
>   choice function.**

(Remark: you are **not** allowed to use the Axiom of Choice in this part of the question)

---

**Pf**:  We can define the choice function $f$ for $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ by $f(S)=\text{the least element of $S$}.$

---

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function),

> A choice function (selector, selection) is a mathematical function f
>   that is defined on some collection X of nonempty sets and assigns to
>   each set S in that collection some element f(S) of S. In other words,
>   f is a choice function for X if and only if it belongs to the direct
>   product of X.

Can someone explain the intuition behind this proof? Thank you.

Comment: If your set is well ordered, every subset of it has a distinguished element, namely, its least element.

Comment: Sort of like "choosing" from an infinite set of pairs of socks: pick the left sock!

Comment: I am trying to break down the definition of a choice function. My understanding is, that if we have a non-empty set $A$ and a non-empty subset $A_{1}$, then we can define ... what exactly? A function that takes $f(A_{1})$ which directly maps into $f(A_{1})$?

Comment: The function itself is a subset of the cartesian product. It consists of every ordered pair $(S, e(S))$, where $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $e(S)$ is the least element of $S$.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. That is a much clearer explanation.

Comment: What, you don't like left socks? (Kidding, ofc!)

Comment: @Chris socks usually don't have left and right... they're Russell's example where AOC *is* required. (Shoes are the example where it isn't.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen My socks have L and R stitched onto them - suck that, Russel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition is that if a set of natural numbers is not empty, then it has a unique least element.

This proves that the relation $\{(S,\min S)\mid S\in\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\setminus\{\varnothing\}\}$ is in fact a function, and by definition a choice function, since $\min S\in S$.